# ¿Como puedo instalar de manera adecuada tsparticles para React Vite?

Tags: reactjs, vite

Buenos dias tengo un problema a la hora de instalar tsparticles en react vite, utilizando javascript + swc en el cual me tira el siguiente mensaje de error,

index.js:15 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null at Vector.js:7:29

yo instale tal cual decia la pagina de tsparticles/react:
https://github.com/tsparticles/react/#readme

por lo que estuve mirando me dice como que tengo importaciones circulares en los archivos que se encuentran en @tsparticles/../Vector y Vector3d pero no se como solucionarlo a eso y no entiendo el porque me lo hace en Vite pero si quiero utilizar el tsparticles en create react app  no me da ese error instalandolo de la misma forma.

Answer (score 0):

tambien queria decir que esas importaciones circulares que eran con el archivo `@tsparticles/../Vector.js Vector3d.js` y un archivo `Utils.js` que se encuentra tambien en `@tsparticles` el cual exporta una `function {isNumber}` y es importada en `Vector3d.js`, a su vez el archivo `Utils.js` importa un `{Vector}` de `Vector.js`. Lo que se me ocurrio fue crear otro archivo llamado `isNumber.js` el cual exporte esa `function {isNumber}` y pueda ser importada en mi `Vector3d.js` para ver si se solucionaba y no sucedio eso.